# Anonymous class with methodMissing

Tags: groovy, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

For a DSL I'm writing I'd like to sometimes return a dummy object that just ignores all the calls.

This works:

```
class Dummy {
    def methodMissing(String name, args) { print "Ignoring: "+name+" "+args }
}

def foo(guardCondition) {

    if (guardCondition)
        return new Dummy()

    // ...
}

foo(true).with { bar('baz') }
```

but if I try to use an anonymous class the result is an error like `No signature of method: <filename>.bar() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [baz]`

Namely this doesn't work:

```
    if (guardCondition)
        return new Object() { def methodMissing(String name, args) { print "Ignoring: "+name+" "+args } }
```

neither does a "bag" approach work:

```
    if (guardCondition)
        return [ methodMissing : { name, args -> print "Ignoring: "+name+" "+args } ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue about this : [GROOVY-4862](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4862). In fact, it doesn't work in a inner class, anonymous or not.